# Host service dictionary categorisation

Tags: python

The dictionary I created is not the output I want, I have no idea what wrong with my code.

The code is below:

```
hostInfoDict = {
'192.168.247.62': {80: 'http', 8080: 'http-proxy'}, 
'192.168.247.64': {80: 'http', 8080: 'http-proxy'}, 
'192.168.247.74': {80: 'http', 8080: 'http-proxy'}
}

for host, hostInfo in hostInfoDict.items():

    httpHostStatusDict = {}

    for port in hostInfo.keys():
        urls = 'http://' + host + ":" + str(port) + '/thredds/catalog.html'
        #print(urls)
        try:
            r = requests.get(urls, timeout=0.5, allow_redirects=False)
            #print(urls, r.status_code)
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
            """An HTTP error occurred."""
            pass
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            """A Connection error occurred."""
            pass
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
            """
            The request timed out while trying to connect to the remote server.

            Requests that produced this error are safe to retry.
            """
            pass
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
            """
            There was an ambiguous exception that occurred while handling your request.
            """
            pass

        try:
            if urls not in httpHostStatusDict:
                httpHostStatusDict[urls] = str(r.status_code)
        except:
            pass
    print(httpHostStatusDict)
```

The output of the above code is shown as following. They are separated instead of a whole dictionary.

```
{'http://192.168.247.62:80/thredds/catalog.html': '200', 'http://192.168.247.62:8080/thredds/catalog.html': '200'}
{'http://192.168.247.64:80/thredds/catalog.html': '404', 'http://192.168.247.64:8080/thredds/catalog.html': '404'}
{'http://192.168.247.74:80/thredds/catalog.html': '200', 'http://192.168.247.74:8080/thredds/catalog.html': '200'}
```

The expected output is

```
{
 {'http://192.168.247.62:80/thredds/catalog.html': '200'},
 {'http://192.168.247.62:8080/thredds/catalog.html': '200'},
 {'http://192.168.247.64:80/thredds/catalog.html': '404'}, 
 {'http://192.168.247.64:8080/thredds/catalog.html': '404'},
 {'http://192.168.247.74:80/thredds/catalog.html': '200'}, 
 {'http://192.168.247.74:8080/thredds/catalog.html': '200'}
}
```

This is a Python REQUEST project :) I think it is a code issue so I don't think you need to install that library.
Your help is my appreciate.

Comment: Just a little FYI: f-strings are more efficient than string concatenation. They also look a lot cleaner! :) `url = f'http://{host}:{port}/thredds/catalog.html'`

Answer (score 1):

You should put httpHostStatusDict = {} before the first for loop, and print should after the whole first for codes.